# How to create an "empty" partial index, or equivalent, in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have a boolean column that will be false for >99.9% of the rows. I need to efficiently fetch all rows where that column is true.

What's the best option? Creating an index on the column? Creating a partial index where the column is true? But I don't know what columns the partial index would / should hold.

This doesn't parse, but is there any way to do something like: `CREATE INDEX mytable_cond ON mytable () WHERE cond = TRUE;` ? Where the index holds literally zero columns?

Comment: [Partial index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html)

Comment: Yes, but on what rows? What rows do I put in ( )?

Comment: What other columns do you have in the table? Will you ever restrict on those too? How many rows are true?

Comment: No, I only need to fetch where this one boolean column is true. There are many other columns. I have some other complicated indexes for the other common query. Less than one in a thousand rows will have this column as true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saying "rows" where I think you mean "columns".

It is not legal to specify an empty list of columns in an index.  Just pick a column, preferably one with a short data type.  If nothing else, just repeat the same column in both places.

```
CREATE INDEX mytable_cond ON mytable (cond) WHERE cond = TRUE;
```

Be careful how you formulate our index and queries.  A `cond = true` query cannot use a partial index defined where `cond is true` and vice versa, those are not considered equivalent operations.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct, I have edited my question to say "columns". I will just make a partial index like you say on the column itself, where the value is true.

Comment: @lurfjurv: I would probably include the primary key or some other frequently used columns into the index.

Comment: I'm curious; why? Is it so that the query can become index-only if I'm only fetching a few of the columns? Or another reason?